# How to check if class exists somewhere in package?

Tags: java, android, security

I'm currently dealing with a particular issue with my paid application.  Internally it contains a licensing check.  The app is patched by hackers by modifying the app apk/jar.  They are adding a new class which helps bypass the licensing check.

My goal is to somehow check for this particular patch.  If I find it I know my app has been compromised.

**Any tips on how to know that something has been modified on the package?**  Doing a hash over the app is not really an option in my case.

I thought maybe checking if this class exists would help, but what if they change the name of the class? Then, another idea is somehow check for unexpected includes added to the class.

Any of these possible? Any suggestions would help :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Not sure about android but in standard JDK you would do something like this:

```
try {
 Class.forName( "your.fqdn.class.name" );
} catch( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
 //my class isn't there!
}
```

Comment: The problem with this call is that it specifies the package name.  The package name is random... But the file name is not...

Comment: so you want to look for a class that is in the same package as the class you check it from? is this the question?

Comment: I need to find a class which can be located randomly anywhere in my app. The class is placed randomly by the "hack patch"

Comment: Well I already knew about this call and was using it... In reality there wasn't a correct answer at this post but since I ended up using this particular check and you where the first to post I'll assign you the correct answer.

Comment: This could throw a NoClassDefFoundError which shall not be caught because it is an error.

Answer (score 19):

Here is what I used in Android - standard Java:

```
public boolean isClass(String className) {
    try  {
        Class.forName(className);
        return true;
    }  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Implementation example:

```
if (isClass("android.app.ActionBar")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
public static Class<?> forName (String className)
```

and check the `ClassNotFoundException`

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Same issue with @Liv post... This doesn't work since I would have to specify the exact path in the package the class is found.  In my case the class could be somewhere randomly stored in my apps package.

Comment: with the risk of being a b**ch -- is this different to what I suggested?

Comment: @Liv have you seen the time difference between the two answers? No, it's not very different. What's the point?

Comment: @Moto please update your question explaining how that hack works so we have a better idea. As of now I don't really understand what do you need.

Answer (score 2):

How does it get loaded if it's a random class in a random package?

That being said, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29 and java.class.path.  For normal java apps, you have to walk the classpath and then search the entries (for jars) or directories (for .class files).  But in a container-class-loader environment, this will fail to work (and I'm not sure how that applies to an android environment).

Comment: Thanks for the response... Well it gets loaded after official release of the application. This particular file bypasses the licensing checks... Than it's distributed freely.

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking what in your official app loads the class if you don't know beforehand what package it is in.  Classes are loaded in response to being referenced from other classes, or loaded via SPI or some other mechanism.  Just having a class in a jar wouldn't be enough by itself to load it.

Comment: That's an interesting point.  Well I'm assuming this patch class is attached to my licensing checking.  Not sure exactly where but I know it should be loaded once I run my licensing check.

Comment: Yep... Decompiled my hacked app and all over I see the include to this particular patch file....