# Best Design Pattern to Implement while Mapping Actions in MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns

What could be the best practices of writing the following case:

We have a controller which based on what paths users take, take different actions. For example:

if user chooses the path /path1/hello it will say hello. If a user chooses /path1/bye?name="Philipp" it will invoke sayGoodBye() and etc.

I have written a switch statement inside the controller which is simple, however IMO not efficient. What are the best way to implement this, considering that paths are generally String.

```
private void takeAction()
    {
    switch (path[1])
    {
    case "hello":
        //sayHello();
        break;
    case "bye":
        //sayBye();
        break;
    case "case3":
        //Blah();
        break;
             ...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** In my context, the path is dynamically generated, meaning that there are not specific pages to be there. If the path is /Amir/ then Amir will be dynamically generated.
Therefore, as Mark Leighton Fisher explained, it is rather difficult to put them in hashes.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Choose an MVC framework that does that for you (and much more).

Comment: @JBNizet , it is one of the most prevailing banes of Java developers. You tend to use frameworks without understanding the underlaying concepts. I would say making a routing mechanism (especially if done for educational purposes) is a good idea. Later then you can pick the framework. But you will have a clear understanding of problems, which are solved by that exact part of said framework.

Comment: No problem if it's purely for educational purpose, and you throw away the code after that to use a well-tested, established framework. But don't fall into the NIH syndrome trap.

Comment: @JBNizet , as a PHP developer I can say that sometimes you *have to* reinvent the wheel, because there are situations when all the "popular" wheels are not even remotely elliptical.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller has taken up additional responsibility: *URL routing*.

Instead this should be performed before the controller's method is executed. The  as nothing to do with your controller. Most obvious pattern you could look at could be [*front controller*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html).

As for the specific implementation, the simplest way would be to create a `Router` instance, which produces a `Request` object from user's input (both the URL itself and other parameters, like `POST` values). The you extract both the name of controller and the method from this `Request` object.

Further-more, it would be reasonable to provide said `Request` instance as parameter for the `action`, so that this action has a clear access to other values from user's input.

You might also find this beneficial: [Spring  Framework docs for DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s02.html)

Comment: In case I am working with Java SE, I was wondering how can I implement the same features safely. I am woking with sun's built-in HttpServer.

Comment: Well. All you controllers would be in separate namespace/package. You just check, if the URL that user requested maps to [exiting class withing said namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794227/how-to-check-if-class-exists-somewhere-in-package).  As for checking, if action exists in controller, there is alread an [exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html).

Comment: Why not just directly put the code that e.g for example if value is login, then create the first controller, if it is user create second controller and ... ?

Answer (score 1):

It is cleaner and faster to use hashes than Switch statements for the actual routing, especially when you have many routes and you are only testing for String equality.

Comment: How can you implement that? I have 3 controllers which implement a single interface. I want to invoke those classes based on the routing. I cannot see how hashes are related in this context