# Android - Honeywell Dolphin - How to detect Laser Scanner

Tags: java, android, qr-code, barcode-scanner, honeywell

I hope find some help from anyone who has worked on Honeywell Dolphin devices.
I'm developing an Android barcode/qr code scan app for multi-devices and the major devices are Dolphin devices. (e.g Dolphin 70e Black)

But to get an app with full compatibility between all phones, I want to detect programmatically if the device which run the apps has the Laser Scanner with the android sdk, else the app, scan with Camera from device.

My issue, is that i didn't found help on web and Honeywell's docs.

If anyone can help me, that will be very cool !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found two solutions two solutions for my issue.

1st : Detect the device's model

```
public static boolean isDolphinDevice() {
    return Build.MODEL.toLowerCase().contains("dolphin");
}
```

Where "dolphin" is a part of the device's model.

And 2nd : check if the apps can loads Honeywell's libs

Like this :
[How to check if class exists somewhere in package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794227/how-to-check-if-class-exists-somewhere-in-package)

Bye ! :)