# Is there a way to detect programmaticaly laser scanner in an android mobile?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, scanning

I have an android mobile with a laser scanner and I wanted to know if there is any way to detect programmatically if a mobile has a laser scanner or not.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585811/android-honeywell-dolphin-how-to-detect-laser-scanner

Comment: no, that is only for dolphin devices

Comment: Perhaps this article may be of some help. [Android: Get Hardware Information Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10496872/9014308)

Comment: I don't think there is an API for this that's why people use these hacks solutions . Can u Somehow use Exception as an validation ? call the laser Scanner API if its not present then it must throw an Exception . This is just a wild shot .

Comment: yeah, I already tried doing what is said on this answer: [Android: get hardware information programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496872/android-get-hardware-information-programmatically), but I didn't find some property for the laser scanner

Comment: The presence or absence of a laser scanner will not be stated directly in the information. However, it is possible to determine the presence or absence of a laser scanner based on information such as the manufacturer, model, and board, etc. Or, based on them, you can decide which SDK/library to use to get the laser scanner information.

Comment: @ladytoky0 Have you got the solution that how to get QR code value/result once we scan any QR code using laser scanner ?