# ImageJ java API: how to test if command exists?

Tags: java, imagej

In a custom ImageJ plugin, before `IJ.run(imp, myCommand, myArguments)` I would like to check if  `myCommand` exists and if not - try another command.

There doesn't seem to be a method for this purpose in the [IJ class](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/IJ.html). What are the alternatives to `try {} catch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some alternatives:

1. Write an [ImageJ2](http://imagej.net/Writing_ImageJ2_plugins) plugin so your command will be automatically exposed in the framework, e.g. in the [CommandService](https://github.com/scijava/scijava-common/blob/scijava-common-2.44.2/src/main/java/org/scijava/command/CommandService.java). This would also allow you to use prioritization of plugins, which it sounds is potentially what you're looking for.
2. You could use [Menus.getCommands()](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/v1.50a/src/main/java/ij/Menus.java#L1246-L1248): `if (Menus.getCommands().get(command) != null) IJ.run(command);`
3. `Try...catch` a [`Class.forName` call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794227/how-to-check-if-class-exists-somewhere-in-package)

Comment: Great answer! I've chosen the second alternative for the time being.