# How to quickly check if a class exists

Tags: java

I want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5794247/4714970):

```
  try {
    Class.forName( "your.fqdn.class.name" );
  } catch( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
  //my class isn't there!
}
```

However I need to do it far more quickly. Execution time of `Class.forName(name)` is about 200ms for me and this is not good enough.

Is there a faster way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Yikes! Don't know how that ended up there. My bad. Remove all.

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner

Comment: I think this could help you http://njbartlett.name/2010/08/30/osgi-readiness-loading-classes.html