# Detect added libraries to pirated Android app?

Tags: android

It appears from my crash reports that some people pirate my app and add advertisements to monetise it.

The stack trace from the crash report seems to show a bunch of calls to a library to show interstitials?

Is it possible for me to add code to detect the presence of the com.test.ylh or com.qq.e library?

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@da2c866 is not valid; is your activity running?
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1126)
  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:439)
  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:473)
  at com.qq.e.comm.plugin.intersitial2.e.a(A:315)
  at com.qq.e.comm.plugin.intersitial2.e.show(A:113)
  at com.qq.e.comm.plugin.intersitial2.e.show(A:107)
  at com.qq.e.comm.plugin.intersitial2.d.show(A:35)
  at com.qq.e.ads.interstitial2.UnifiedInterstitialAD.show(Unknown Source:4)
  at com.test.ylh.InterAd$2.run(InterAd.java:53)
  at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6972)
  at com.test.ylh.InterAd.showAd(InterAd.java:50)
  at com.test.ylh.InterAd.onADReceive(InterAd.java:108)
  at com.qq.e.comm.plugin.intersitial2.a$1.run(A:169)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a class exists with a method as described over here: [How to check if class exists somewhere in package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794227/how-to-check-if-class-exists-somewhere-in-package)

However, they could also remove that check when recompiling the app. So it won't be airtight. You can make it more difficult for the "pirates" by adding proper code obfuscation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#obfuscate